# .gitignore ignore directories/packages matching patterns

Tags: git, github, gitignore

So, I'm trying to exclude all the python packages in my project.

For example-

```
project/
|--- dir1/
|    |-- pymysql/
|    |-- PyMySQL-0.8.0.dist-info/
|
|--- dir2/
|    |-- pymysql/
|    |-- PyMySQL-1.8.0.dist-info/
```

Now I need to ignore all the occurences of `pymysql` and `PyMySQL`(regardless of the dist version) from all my directories.

Having `*pymysql/` and `*PyMySQL*/` in `.gitignore` seems to work fine here.

But, is there any better/efficient way to do this since I could have any number of packages in my project - and I'll have to hardcode each of them in my `.gitignore` in this case.

Answer (score 2):

> I just need to know if there's an easier way to exclude all possible Python packages in my project in `.gitignore`.

You can check a typical [`Python.gitignore`](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Python.gitignore) file, but using glob pattern like you did (provided you know of a consistent naming convention) is a good start.
Then .gitignore mentioned does add other folders:

```
# Distribution / packaging
.Python
build/
develop-eggs/
dist/
downloads/
eggs/
.eggs/
lib/
lib64/
parts/
sdist/
var/
wheels/
pip-wheel-metadata/
share/python-wheels/
*.egg-info/
.installed.cfg
*.egg
MANIFEST
```

Comment: thanks for the info. I guess for all other miscellaneous package directories, I'll just have to look at their patterns and hard-code them into my `.gitignore`. Would be nice to have a feature that just excludes all Python or any other language related package directories by a single line in `.gitignore`.

Answer (score 0):

I tested this and `*pymysql/` and `*PyMySQL*/` do seem to work. Now I just need to know if there's an easier way to exclude all possible Python packages in my project in `.gitignore`.